# Legacy OpenGL texturing cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to texture a cuboid in legacy OpenGL. No matter which side of the cuboid I render first, this side is not textured correctly where as all other sides are textured correctly. I have tried rendering different sides of the cube first.

This is the code that draws the cube including it's texture coordinates:

```
void Objects::cuboidTextured(float width, float height, float depth, float xpos, float ypos, float zpos, float r, float g, float b){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos);

    glColor3f(r, g, b);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(  width, -height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f(  width,  height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f( width, -height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f( width,  height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( width,  height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f( width, -height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height, depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(  width,  height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f(  width,  height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(  width, -height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f(  width, -height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height,  depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height, -depth );
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f( -width, -height, -depth);       
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f( -width,  height, -depth);      
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f(  width,  height, -depth);      
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f(  width, -height, -depth); 
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: please add the rendered result

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it backwards, calling `glVertex()` before `glTexCoord()`.

[`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml):

> glVertex commands are used within glBegin/glEnd pairs to specify
>               point, line, and polygon vertices.  The **current color, normal, texture
>               coordinates, and fog coordinate** are associated with the vertex when glVertex
>               is called.

So, set all your vertex state by `glTexCoord()` and friends, *then* call `glVertex()`:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);
glVertex3f( width, -height, -depth );
glTexCoord2f(1,1);
glVertex3f( width,  height, -depth );
glTexCoord2f(0,1);
glVertex3f( width,  height,  depth );
glTexCoord2f(0,0);
glVertex3f( width, -height,  depth );
glEnd();
```

Otherwise `glVertex()` will use whatever random texture coordinate was last set.